# $X$ a $2\times 2$ matrix, find $Y$ such that $Y^{n}=X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

This problem is a subset of master course examinations .

I am little good at linear algebra of transfer examinations however I had never saw this problem during studying for 3rd year transfer examinations .

$$  X:= \pmatrix{5&3\\2&6}   $$

As $~  Y^{n}=X ~$ is held for $~ n \in \mathbb{N}  ~$ , Find out $~ Y ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{This statemant is as same as the problem statement }  ~$

I rewrote the above to the down one . I think both are completely same .

Find out $~ Y \ni Y^{n}=X  ~~ \leftarrow~~ n \in\mathbb{N} ~$

Which website(s) for formula(s) should I refer , to solve this problem?

Comment: It is really unclear how you are using left arrows. If it is an input to the question, usually we write input information before the question, not as an afterthought.

Comment: I will edit of it.

Comment: Also, I assume you are using $\ni$ to mean “such that.” It is usually better to use words rather than symbols, for easier reading. Symbols like $\ni$ are good for blackboards, where space and time make usage of such symbols a convenience and the words are still spoken by the lecturer. But we prefer to just use the words in other contexts.

Comment: Sorry , my computer has been forcefully shutdowned for 8 hours , so I cant edit my post for a while.

Comment: If $n$ is an input, then this is not true. E.g. $n=2$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},$ there is no real matrix $Y.$

Comment: Sorry , I have elements of X .

Comment: x11=5,  x12 =3, x21=2, x22=6

Comment: Hint: Diagonalize $X.$ It is much easier to take roots of diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to diagonalise matrices, you will get using standard methods:
$$X=P\,D\,P^{-1}$$
with
$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3/2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$D = \begin{bmatrix} 8 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$
It is not hard to show that for any integer $n \geq 1$ and any matrix $A$:
$$(P\,A\,P^{-1})^n = P\,A^n\,P^{-1}$$
So if one takes:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 8^{1/n} & 0 \\ 0 & 3^{1/n} \end{bmatrix}$$
one gets $A^n = D$ so:
$$ (P\,A\,P^{-1})^n = P\,A^n\,P^{-1} = P\,D\,P^{-1} = X$$
So one possible solution is
$$Y = P\,A\,P^{-1}$$

Comment: I will check it later sorry .

Comment: I think I understood for this post . Thank you.